# How to get rid of the array part next to the output

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I've been working on this algorithm that works on understanding genetic code. This is a small problem but it's just not desirable.

This is the code:

```py
import numpy as np

A = [1, 0, 0, 0]
C = [0, 1, 0, 0]
T = [0, 0, 1, 0]
G = [0, 0, 0, 1]
original = [A, T, T, G, C, G]
copy = [C, T, T, A, T, A]

x = [1 if 1 in j else 0 for i, v in enumerate(original) for j in zip(v, copy[i])]

new = np.array_split(x, len(original))
print(new)
```

The output is:

> [**array**([1, 1, 0, 0]), **array**([0, 0, 1, 0]), **array**([0, 0, 1, 0]), **array**([1, 0, 0, 1]), **array**([0, 1, 1, 0]), **array**([1, 0, 0, 1])]

It works but it would be preferred if the output doesn't have the array parts that are bolded. I'm sort of new to programming but with the experience I have, I haven't really encountered something like this. Also, I would also like it if each array had it's own line so it's easier to understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: definitely! I didn't realize that but I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`print(*new, sep='\n')`

Should do the trick.

Comment: How to get rid of the bold, though?

Comment: This is how the output looks like on my machine running python 3.6.9 `[1 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[1 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 1]`

Comment: Ok, then, let me try on python 3.5.